# git push to production not creates var/www/laravel

Tags: git

I have created post-receive file in `hooks`, added there

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/laravel --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git checkout -f
```

Added permission `sudo chmod +x post-receive` , added from my pc `git remote add production ssh://root@myipaddress/var/repo/site.git`, pushed it `git push production master` . Files were pushed, but nothing happened on the server. `git push production master` tells everithing is up-to-date. Folder var/www/laravel was not created. Why can't I deploy?

Comment: Perhaps it happens, because Git does not track empty folders?

Comment: I'm not a "PRO" of git. As I know, it should create them, because I initialized "--bare".